# ImageView: change image on press, and on release

Tags: android, android-imageview

I would change imageView picture when it's pressed, and change it again when pressure is released. That ImageView contains picture of a button, and when is pressed i would give to user a feedback (like when he press a normal button) by change image. This is my code:

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + event.toString());
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_hover);
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.button);
        }
        }
        return false;
    }
    });
```

and this is xml

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="std_button"
    android:src="@drawable/button" />
```

but it doesn't work. If i use only ACTION_DOWN event, image change as i want,
What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try add break; after each case,

And as giozh said inside onTouch i return always false, so touch event result always not consumed. Just put return true after each case statement.

Comment: Also, no brackets are needed when writing a switch-case.

Comment: I've use your suggestion and i solved my problem in different way! inside onTouch i return always false, so touch event result always not consumed. Just put return true after each case statement.

Comment: How can you return true and break after each case? Place one of them will skip the other.

Answer (score 7):

Make selector xml in drawable folder with content like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_green" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_red"/>
    </selector>
```

Comment: make this drawable xml file as  android:src="@drawable/selector"

Comment: I've try but it doesn't work. However i need to do that via programmatically. Thanks anyway

Comment: @giozh - virtually anything declared in XML in Android can be done programmatically as well.

Comment: Works perfect! Tested on Android API 23

Answer (score 0):

for change on event press you can try this.....

```
final ImageView imagen = (Imagen) findViewById(R.id.imageViewX);
 ImageView imagen = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewX);
     imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             ImageView perse = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewX);
             perse.setImageResource(R.drawable.backgroundtwo);

         }
     });
```

Comment: This is not the answer. The break statement is missing in the actual OP code. Also you cannot re-init a final variable.

Comment: not only with a break function, also with counter++