# How to change drawable image background while click

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

I am new to Android, I have an image, want to change background color programmatically while clicking that icon. How to do. Please, anyone help me.

I have icon like this, before click:

[image: Before Click]

I want to change like this while click, after click:

[image: After click]

Comment: Take a look at this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404602/imageview-change-image-on-press-and-on-release](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404602/imageview-change-image-on-press-and-on-release)

Answer (score 0):

You have to see:

[how to apply click event listener to image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839273/how-to-apply-click-event-listener-to-image-in-android)

and inside of the click event listener:

```
backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

or

```
backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 50));
```

Comment: I know click listener... I don't want change image... Just change background color

Comment: Ops, i am sorry.
You can use: backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

I have edit the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is a selector.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

And then you need to create the two images, because from what I see in the examples you also set the text color.

If you later want to change the overall color of the icon you can do that using AppCompatImageView and tinting.

Answer (score 0):

**Two Solution Available**

1. Use Two Images and update on android:state_selected, android:state_pressed. Similar to dzsonni answer.
2. Use SVG Image.Update Programmatically.See Below link
   [Dynamically changing SVG Image colours on Android](https://medium.com/@emmaguy/dynamically-changing-svg-colours-on-android-b026a99137ad#.tyureshqk)